# How to arange image in div in Joomla tooltip?

Tags: html, css, joomla, tooltip, joomla2.5

I am using [JHtml::tooltip](http://docs.joomla.org/JHtml::tooltip/1.6) to show my tooltips in component, but the problem is in image position. I tried to add `bottom:0%`, `bottom:0px`.

So here is what i have:

[image]

I need that image would be inline with text. Here is my code:

```
<div class="serch">
    <div class="advanced_search">
        <span id="advanced_search">Advanced Search</span>
        <span>
            Search: 
            <a href="#"><span id="advanced_search_by_branch"><b>By Branch</b></span></a> |
            <a href="#"><span id="advanced_search_by_address">By Address</span></a> |
            <a href="#"><span id="advanced_search_by_tel">By Telephone Number</span></a> 
            <?php echo JHTML::tooltip('This is a tooltip attached to text', 'Text Tooltip Title', 'tooltip.png');?>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style included here are null. Here is also source from firebug:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
.hasTip img {vertical-align: baseline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a simple `.hasTip img { margin-top: 10px; }` to move it down 10px, changing that to get it just right.

Comment: it pulls full div, not image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try inline css...

```
<img alt="Tooltip" src="/~nonamez/joomla/media/..../tooltip.png" style="margin-top:10px;">..
```